# Can Youtube URLs be a landing page for ads?

Tags: advertising, bing, youtube, landing-page

I'm trying to run ADs on Bing Ads with Youtube watch pages as the destination pages. I was previously doing it using AdWords video campaigns, but I got attracted by Bing Ads and figured I would give it a try. However, I started wondering if those ads will actually work considering that the landing page is Youtube and not a website I own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bing Ad Content and Style Guidelines for Landing Pages](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-ca/editorial-ad-content-guidelines#AC15) don't say anything about you having to own the site of the landing page.

They have [more guidelines about landing page quality](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/editorial-guidelines) in terms of site design and intellectual property (infringing on trademarks).  But again, I don't see anything about having to own the site that you are directing advertising towards.

It looks like they allow ads to any site.